# passing parameter in onLoad funtion (html and js)

Tags: javascript, html, function

im trying to make a tic tac toe game i have 2 buttons (single player and 2 players) and i need to pass an int for the user to choose (depanding on the button picked) and change the value in my js,

my html:

```
<body onload="startGame(i);">   //this is the parameter i want to use
      <table>
           // code......
      </table>

      </br>
      <div id= "menu" class="animated bounceInLeft"> <!-- Buttons -->

            <a href = "javascript:startGame(1);" class = "animated shake">Single player</a> // the single player button
            <a href = "javascript:startGame(2);" class = "animated shake">Two players</a> // to 2 players button
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

js:

```
var choise = 0; //global

function startGame(i){
    if (i == 1)
        choise = 1;     //change according to parameter
    else
        choise = 1;
}
```

is it possible?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a value that the user chooses in response to the document loading. The document loading isn't something that happens in response to a choice. (Unless the choice was made on a previous page, in which case you have to pass the value to the new document in some fashion — such as a query string or local storage — and then read it back from there.)

You either wait for a button to be clicked or you put a value in to the argument. (In the code in the question, the `i` in the `onload` attribute is undefined).

Comment: i want the page to change according to the button pressed ofcourse.. how can i  manage that?

Comment: If by "change" you mean "load a new page" then you use a regular link instead of JavaScript. If you mean "modify the existing DOM" then you make your JavaScript function do something more interesting that set a variable (and, ideally, learn about `addEventListener` and progressive enhancement). Either way, you don't use `onload`.